# How to uninstall .deb python module

Tags: python, dpkg

I have python2.7 default n ubuntu(64bit) , I have wrongly installed a python module (UNO module) which is for 32bit arch.

**how I have installed**

1. wget (uno-module32-version).deb
2. dpkg -i (uno-module32-version).deb

What is the safe way to uninstall this python module, so that I can install 64bit version.

**Update1**:

when I tried installing 64 version(while 32bit version is still installed):

```
dpkg -i python-uno_3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

It gave me error:

```
dpkg: error processing python-uno_3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 python-uno: 1:3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with python-uno:i386 1:3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1 (Multi-Arch: no) which is currently installed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-uno_3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: i think you should install the 64-bit version, before uninstalling the 32-bit version.

Comment: I have tried that, but it gave me error. please check the update.

Comment: To uninstall try either `dpkg -r python-uno` or `apt-get remove python-uno`.

Comment: Hi mike, sorry my answer is exact as you r answer. I had not seen your comment while writing my answer, But thank you anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I researched a little and it has a simple solution for this;

**Here are the steps:**

1.Find the exact name of the package you want to uninstall:

`dpkg -l | grep 'uno'` (in my case)

it will show you output as :(in my case)

```
iU  python-uno                           1:3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1                  Python-UNO bridge
```

2.Copy the name,  Then just do :

> dpkg -r **python-uno**

It will uninstall the package.